# What's the max amount of char variables I can compare with operators in C?

Tags: c

I want to know if I'm doing the char variable comparison correctly. Here's an example:

```
char turn;
printf("Insert turn: ");
scanf("%c", &turn);
while((turn != 'M') && (turn != 'T') && (turn != 'N'))
{
    printf("Wrong, insert a new turn: ");
    scanf("%c", &turn);
}
```

Inside the parenthesis of the while function, can I use operators with three values? Am I using the wrong syntax or is it not possible to do so?

Comment: THere's no problem chaining multiple "and" operators. But - you would know that if you simply compiled your code. If the compiler doesn't complain, then you're good.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Could you describe the problem you are trying to overcome? It is not clear what it is you are trying to make possible.

Comment: @jxh: Actually, the problem description is there. OP is asking a syntactic question.

Comment: @einpoklum: Perhaps. The question "can i use operators with three values" is unclear. It is certainly not true of binary operators. "Am i using the wrong syntax or is it not possible...?" is also not clear, since the expectations are not specified.

Comment: It does not show any errors, but when i run the code, it skips the first scanf and enters the while, printing whats inside it, even if i assign the turn variable with M T or N.  Also after that, whatever i insert,  i can't get past it

Comment: @jxh: I was not very clear maybe, what i wanted to know (because the code is not working) is if it is correct to chain all those and operators, taking into account that they're char variables. Also i was wondering if the syntax is correct or if shouldn't separate each statement " turn != 'X' " with parenthesis

Comment: It looks like it is working to me.  Try it here: https://onlinegdb.com/BkSupyfsI   But you are right the parenthesis are redundant.

Comment: Aha,  I read your comment that said "It does not show any errors, but when i run the code, it skips the first scanf and enters the while, printing whats inside it, even if i assign the turn variable with M T or N. Also after that, whatever i insert, i can't get past it" - That should have been part of the question.  You need to ignore whitespace including the enter key which is also in the string.  Change your `scanf("%c", &turn);` to `scanf(" %c", &turn);` so that leading whitespace is ignored like I did in the example I gave in the other comment.

Comment: Thanks for your answers i think the error is related to the rest of the program which i haven't pasted here. Anyways you solved some of my issues so thanks a lot

Comment: @einpoklum "If the compiler doesn't complain, then you're good.". That's not necessarily true. A lot of invalid code can compile. A lot of code is valid for one compiler but not for another, due to extensions and particular choices when confronted with undefined or implementation defined behavior.

Comment: The test could be simplified as `while (!strchr("MTN", turn))`

Comment: @Oppen: I only meant this w.r.t. OP's question. But let me qualify that... If the compiler doesn't complain when you've told it to strictly adhere to the C++ standard, then your syntax is most probably valid.

Answer (score 3):

> What's the max amount of char variables i can compare with operators?

To address the title question:
Certainly you can perform the 3 compares in one line - but how far can we go?

C does have *translation limits* including  *at least* 4095 characters in a logical source line.  With `(turn != 'M') &&` and `(turn != 'T') &&` ... looks like 250+ compares could be done.  Although no one would like to read that line of code, a compliant compiler should handle it.

---

Note that `scanf("%c", &turn);` also reads an <kbd>Enter</kbd> as a `'\n'`.  You might want
`scanf(" %c", &turn);`  (add space) to first consume leading white-space.

Answer (score 0):

As already mentioned in the comments, your char variable comparison is done correctly. I would suggest for you just to use a compiler and see if it compiles right and work fine. There is no need to check for the right syntex if it works just fine. But, I'll correct you for some other things.

1. Always intialize variables:

   ```
   char turn = 0;
   ```
2. For buffer cleaning use getchar() at the end of every scanf() use:

   ```c
   scanf("%c", &turn);
   getchar();
   ```
3. You may as well just use the getchar() function:

   ```c
   turn = getchar();
   ```

For the full fixed version of code:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char turn = 0;
    printf("Insert turn: ");
    scanf("%c", &turn);
    getchar();

    while ((turn != 'M') && (turn != 'T') && (turn != 'N')) {
        printf("Wrong, insert a new turn: ");
        scanf("%c", &turn);
        getchar();
    }

    getchar(); // Just if you want to stop the program at the end.

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your explanation!! I will try what you've explained me and keep looking for more info to get my code working. Thanks again!